Sqlite CreateTable BLOB "Don't know about ...Blob" Not working
CommunityToolkitMAUI, Sqlite-Net-Pcl
Currently targeting only Android 14. (Also tried and failed on Windows Machine (same error))
In this app I'm making a point of using code first conn.CreateTable<myModel>() instead of lengthy Sql Creates, but I'm getting a lot of "Don't know about..." errors.    In this case the class was simple enough and building ok with ints and strings until I tried to add another Blob field to store an image / byte[].

public partial class BreedModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int id;
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string name;
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string bred_for;
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string breed_group;
    ...
    ...

    [ObservableProperty]   ///only have problems when adding this field.
    private Blob localImage;

}```


ObservableObject is for your ViewModel, not your model. Create a POCO for database access and leave ObservableObject for the ViewModel.

No luck.  I recreated it as a flat POCO, again it only works without Blob.  Works fine in all cases with string and int.  The only time I'm having trouble is in the CreateTable.

This is the Sqlite-Net Table Mappings code.
        else if (clrType == typeof (byte[])) {
        return "blob";
    }

I must use a type of byte[] to get it to work.
[ObservableProperty]
private byte[] localImage;

No information about "Blob" on  MS.com
